# Python - remove duplicate lines with specific key

Tags: python, file, tokenize, duplicates

I have around 500k lines which look like the following in a text file (sample snippet) -

```
1,Party-120273.gif,16256,23ss423
2,Party-120275.gif,16456,23423
3,Party-120273.gif,12656,232423
4,Party-120273.gif,165236,2312423
5,Party-120276.gif,165236,2312423
```

How do I remove the duplicate occurrences of the lines in the file based on the 2nd value value column. For example in the above lines, remove the duplicate occurrences of lines which contain *Party-120273.gif*. One the first occurrence should be left undeleted. Hence the output should be -

```
1,Party-120273.gif,16256,23ss423
2,Party-120275.gif,16456,23423
5,Party-120276.gif,165236,2312423
```

I have to do this for the entire file, and remove the duplicate lines with repeating values in the 2nd column. How would I do this in python?

Comment: The `csv` module and `set` container are your friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be Python? Why not use `sort(1)`:

```
sort --field-separator=, --key=2,2 --unique < file
```

If you still want to do it in Python, look at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to parse the lines:

```
seenKeys = set()
for row in reader:
    if row[1] in seenKeys: continue

    seenKeys.add( row[1] )
    print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: I had earlier tried the sort command. I am working on a remote linux machine and for some reason it doesn't seem to affect any changes to the file. I dont know what maybe the reason... But the python code worked like a gem. I tried the sort command on a Mac, it worked but the results are quite different from the python results

Comment: `sort` is a filter; it doesn't change the file, it prints a new file to `stdout` without the duplicate lines. But it also sorts all lines by key, so the order of many lines change. This doesn't happen with the Python version.